# How to maintain original image dimensions while saving a color filtered image to sd card?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I am building an Android app where I have a requirement of saving a `bitmap` from an `ImageView` which contains a `color-filtered image`. I have been able to successfully implement the app, taking help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206494/how-to-save-an-image-in-sdcard-after-applying-rgb-color-filter-in-android) stackoverflow post, but the color filtered image which is getting stored in sd card is smaller than the original.

Code:

```
private Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
        final int w = v.getWidth();
        final int h = v.getHeight();
        final Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        final Canvas c = new  Canvas(b);
        //v.layout(0, 0, w, h);
        v.layout(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
        v.draw(c);
        return b;
    }
```

I understand that these two lines:

```
final int w = v.getWidth();
final int h = v.getHeight();
```

are causing this, but I cannot figure out what changes I need to make in the code to save
the image in its original `dimensions`.

Answer (score 0):

```
final int w = v.getWidth();
final int h = v.getHeight();
```

takes height and width of image view. you need to get height and width of image itself.

Comment: @ManojitGhosh refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440863/can-i-get-image-file-width-and-height-from-uri-in-android , it will help you somewhat

Comment: That didn't help but, I figured out how to get image dimensions. That half-solved the problem. Sample saved photo: https://flic.kr/p/nukH98